# How to Limit Access to Machines by (Ex: Library Card)

Tags: 12.10

Since I saw no blog about this, I thought I would ask for other peoples' reference.

I was wondering if there is a program for Ubuntu that does something similar to this:
At libraries (which 99% of them run Windows XP) they always have this program that asks you for a valid Library card number ID to access the computers, then it gives you about an hour of computer time before it boots you off. Is there a program that replicates the asking of Library ID, since I know you could use `timekpr` to time it. Thanks:)

Comment: also, doing some research, I found out timekpr isn't working on 11.10+, any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

You could set up users based on library card numbers. This would also allow great control over what the users can do with the systems.  It could be maintained remotely or locally, and you could use a range of tools to administer the system.  The most common access people would want would be the library catalogue and I suggest this should be available with a normal guest login.

Comment: If each library card number is a user, the user log in list could get out of hand fast, not to mention drive space with all those home directories (or am I misunderstanding your answer?)

Comment: You could change how the home directories are handled to something similar to how the guest account works.  Any system that provides any sort of security is going to require some work.  If you just want to give users limited access to the system use the guest account.  You could also investigate setting up a kiosk system - there's a few people doing this but I have no specific recommendations.

Comment: @James, yeah, you'd be talking THOUSANDS of unnecessary user accounts for each number, you understood me.

Comment: @fabricator4 Is there a way where you could make an account have a LOT of different passwords to where the user is 'library' and your library card ID is the password (so there would be thousands of correct passwords?)

Comment: All I want is so only people with valid library cards can use the computers. If it isn't possible I'd just set up an admin and log users in via Guest.